# Async HttpWebResponse gets truncated If the response is of larger size

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I use the below code to get a json string from from a webservice in callback function and the request is requested using a "POST" method

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;                   
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);
Stream streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader streamRead = new StreamReader(streamResponse);
string responseString = streamRead.ReadToEnd();
```

The above code works fare when response length is small, but in a specific case i receive a larger response which is around 1.35mb of size and i am receiving it truncated but i am able to view the complete response in browser and in terminal

Please help, thanks in advance

Comment: The code looks fine. How can you tell it is truncated? What does `responseString.Length` evaluate to?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for looking into it, As the response is a json i got format error by that i found that the response is truncated, i also verified by using a webbrowser, the actual length of the response is some 3400000 chars, but the response string length is 22421 chars only

Comment: Use Fiddler to intercept the HTTP request and look at what the server sent you. Fiddler is not buggy. If Fiddler shows the response as incomplete as well it is the server's fault.

Comment: Yeah i checked with fiddler, webservice sending a proper response

Comment: Ok I honestly had doubts because this code looks good. But that proves your point. I don't know of any plausible cause. I can only recommend that you try to play around with the code hoping to find a clue. Try reading bytes instead of a string to make sure it is not an encoding problem. Try `new WebClient().DownloadString(url)`. Is that also broken? Try `DownloadData` instead.